# How to achieve a finer distribution of columns in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use about 3/12 of the row for a middle column, and have two columns of the same width on both sides (would equal 4.5 out of 12). Is this possible to recreate with the bootstrap grid system? I thought about using nested columns but couldn't come up with a way to make the two outer columns 4.5 wide - the only way I found would be to split the whole page into 2 halfs first, and then divide both halves into 9/12 and 3/12. But then, my middle column would be split apart.

I attached an image to explain it better.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system to 24 cols. @grid-columns=24 
so you will have

```
<div class="col-sm-9"></div> <!-- 4.5 / 12 -->
<div class="col-sm-6"></div> <!-- 3 / 12 -->
<div class="col-sm-9"></div> <!-- 4.5 / 12 -->
```

that should work for you.